# Simply forking and redirecting the output of a command to /dev/null

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, autocomplete, tab-completion

I frequently execute from a shell (in my case Bash) commands that I want to fork immediately and whose output I want to ignore. So frequently in fact that I created a script (`silent`) to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
$@ &> /dev/null &
```

I can then run, e.g.

```
silent inkscape myfile.svg
```

and my terminal will not be polluted by the debug output of the process I just forked.

I have two questions:

1. Is there an "official" way of doing this?, i.e. something shorter but equivalent to `&> /dev/null &` ?
2. If not, is there a way I can make tab-completion work after my `silent` command as if it weren't there ? To give an example, after I've typed `silent inksc`, I'd like bash to auto-complete my command to `silent inkscape` when I press `[tab]`.

Comment: You wrote 'as if it weren't there'. Sorry what is 'it'? Maybe you can edit your post to clarify. Good luck.

Comment: It means making bash treat the arguments to `silent` as a normal command, with normal tab completion available for that command. So `silent git pus[TAB]` would complete to `silent git push`.

Comment: I clarified the second question, thanks for asking. The git example is perhaps even better, as it shows that I'd like bash to use the git completion profile in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aside: probably want to `exec "$@" &> /dev/null &` in your `silent` script, to cause it to discard the sub-shell, and the quotes around `"$@"` will keep spaces from getting in the way.

As for #2: `complete -F _command silent` should do something like what you want. (I call my version of that script `launch` and have `complete -F launch` in my `.bash_profile`)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like nohup does more or less what you want. The tab-completion problem is because bash thinks that you are trying to complete a filename as an argument to the script, whereas its completion rules know that nohup takes a command as its first argument.

Nohup redirects stout and stderr to nohup.out and will also leave the command running if your shell exits.

Comment: I guess `nohup` is almost what I want; it doesn't automatically fork the process, as far as I understand its workings.

Comment: No, but you can use "nohup command &" if you need to run the process in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script I use for launching interactive (and chatty) X apps from e.g. an xterm

```
#!/bin/bash
exe="$1"
shift
"$exe" "$@" 2>/tmp/$$."$exe".err 1>&2 & disown $!
```

No output, won't die if the terminal exits, but in case something goes wrong there's a log of all output in /tmp

If you don't want the log just use /dev/null instead.

Also will work from a function if you're script-alergic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you could 'rebind' the tab key? An [example](https://superuser.com/a/117254) on superuser Stackoverflow with the enter key is shown. Is this the right idea?